# How to optimize conditional cumsum of multiple column

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops

I have very similar dataframe as below:

```
      Date        Col1    Col2    Col3 ...
   2020/11/04     -10      0       12
   2020/11/05      31      12      42
   2020/11/07      10      1      -12
   2020/11/08      2      -15      1
   2020/11/09      2       10      0
   .
   .
   .
```

My cumsum condition is while calculating sum for next row if **sum is negative** change it to 0. Output of the operation should look like below.

```
      Date        Col1    Col2    Col3 ...
   2020/11/04       0      0       12
   2020/11/05      31      12      54
   2020/11/07      41      13      42
   2020/11/08      43      0       43
   2020/11/09      45      10      43
   .
   .
   .
```

I have achieved this by looping and applying condition through each rows and column but for cumbersome data its performance is very poor.

```
columns = diff.columns
    for col in columns:
        if diff.iloc[0].at[col] < 0:
            diff.iloc[0].at[col] = 0
    for i,row in diff.iterrows():
        if not i == diff.first_valid_index():
            prev = diff.index.get_loc(i) - 1
            for col in columns:
                diff.loc[i].at[col] = diff.loc[i].at[col] + diff.iloc[prev].at[col]
                if diff.loc[i].at[col] < 0:
                    diff.loc[i].at[col] = 0
```

How can I do it better way in pandas?

**UPDATE**
this thread [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27935) is very relevant and my solution is:

```
def adj_func(x):
    total = 0
    result = []
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        total += y
        if total < 0:
            total = 0
        result.append(total)
    return result
diff[col_list].apply(adj_func)
```

Comment: for the first row if value is negative set value to 0 otherwise if **sum** is negative

Answer (score 3):

#### `njit`

If you have access to Numba

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def f(a):
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if x < 0:
            a[i:] -= x
    return a

def g(s):
    return f(s.to_numpy().cumsum())

df.assign(**df[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']].apply(g))

         Date  Col1  Col2  Col3
0  2020/11/04     0     0    12
1  2020/11/05    31    12    54
2  2020/11/07    41    13    42
3  2020/11/08    43     0    43
4  2020/11/09    45    10    43
```

Otherwise, without Numba

```
def h(s):
    a = s.to_numpy().cumsum()
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if x < 0:
            a[i:] -= x
    return a

df.assign(**df[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']].apply(h))
```